# Is it possible to use a UIPageViewController to have an in-app tutorial similar to Tweetbot 3 where they're floating above?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I'm somewhat new to `UIPageViewController` and all the tutorials I've read have shown how to use it with full view controllers where you swipe through them. Is it possible to present it on top of an existing View Controller similar to how Tweetbot 3 does this? Or is completely custom-written?

[image]

Comment: That's probably a custom view or view controller using a `UIPageControl`, not a `UIPageViewController`.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you could simply add a custom UIView on top of your current view, that is containing an UIScrollView with pagingEnabled set to YES. You just have to add an additional UIPageControl below it and hook it up to the scrollview. There are tons of tutorials how to do this, like this one: [Tutorial](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/)

Comment: With those the scrollviews extend edge to edge to create the illusion that there's only one at a time, I need one where it's floating in the middle, away from the sides.